# T-SQL convert inner joined table's rows as columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
select a.code, b.translationName 
from Funds a
inner join Translations b ON  a.code = b.code
where a.code= 'xyz123'
```

This query returns a two-row, two-column result as below:

```
code          translationName
---------------------------------------
xyz123       'Fund's chineseName'
xyz123       'Fund's JapaneseName'
```

Is there a way to return the result as

```
code          translatonName1         translationName2
xyz123        'Fund's chineseName'   'Fund's JapaneseName'
```

btw, there is a column `languageId` in `Translations` Table.

Comment: Your code works fine for me, are you sure the two codes are the same? Maybe try ON LTRIM(RTRIM(a.code)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(b.code))

Comment: You will also need specify both translationName fields in your select statement, not just 1 of them.

Comment: Well your query works then, if it displaying on 2 rows then the codes must be different in some way.

Comment: @OwainEsau it's the sane fund that sells in china and japan, the Chinese name and Japanese name are just for displaying purpose, and the fund can be only purchased in USD.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151667/discussion-between-yan-and-owain-esau).

Comment: is there  column in the translations table to identify which language? e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a column in the translations table that identifies language (such as an [ISO 6339-1 code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes)) then you can use case expressions to "pivot" the rows ro columns

```
select
       a.code
     , max(case when b.lang = 'zh' then b.translationName end) as ChineseName
     , max(case when b.lang = 'ja' then b.translationName end) as JapaneseName
from Funds a
inner join Translations b ON  a.code = b.code
where a.code= 'xyz123'
group by
       a.code
```

If there is no language identifier then I don't see how you will align the extra columns sensibly.

Comment: You may also want to include an added condition in the where clause: **and b.lang in ('ja','zh')**

Comment: I followed the logic you used, it's working, `and b.lang in ('ja', 'zh')` is not quite necessary in my case